# How to do a parameterization in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to find an algorithm for the game master mind with 4 numbers, where each number can be between 0 to 5, giving 1296 possibilities. With the first guess being 1,1,0,0
there are less options left.

I would like to know how to remove the options which are not suitable according to the first guess.

How to use an array(solutions) and array(current solutions)? Should I use parameterization for that?

Is there an algorithm in C to do that?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest to implement is to simply loop trough all your elements and make the once that no longer work false. This might be the best idea here as looping trough 1300 elements is still quite fast however be aware that there is a faster solution in just finding which type of solutions are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

For mastermind there are multiple algorithms, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Five-guess_algorithm), however for your first implementation I think they are too difficult.

You could start by using either

- Thijser's idea (slightly better than brute-forcing all possibilities),
- or try to emulate a human player: using that a white key-peg means `correct color in wrong position` and a black key-peg meaning `correct color in correct position`. You can write an easy recursion to take that info into account:

  - white-peg -> move the colors around ;
  - black-peg remove colors to find out which of the colors was the one that was correct-in-correct-pos.